# Is it possible to use array elements as a foreign key in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

Let's say I run the following to create two SQL tables (in PostgreSQL specifically):

```
CREATE TABLE places
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  place_name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE people
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  full_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  place_ids TEXT[] REFERENCES places(id)
);
```

Is it possible to use the `people.place_ids` in a query to join the two tables?

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
JOIN places
ON places.id IN people.place_ids
WHERE people.id = 7;
```

The query is just made up quickly as an example, but is the idea valid? Are we able to use `IN` instead of `=` to reference another table?

Comment: I think you're looking for **ANY**: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-comparisons.html

Comment: FKs are constraints & are not used in querying. What is "referencing another table"? What is stopping you from running this code? What does the manual & other research say? What exactly is your question? [ask] [Help] [mre]

Comment: No, you can't have foreign keys with arrays. If you create a properly normalized model, then you don't need that to begin with. But it is possible to use such an array in a JOIN condition.

Comment: `place_ids TEXT[]` violates 1NF. I would recommend you normalize your database at least to 3NF.

Comment: A FK is a column set whose subrow values appear elsewhere as UNIQUE. From your code you clearly don't mean "use an array as a foreign key" since you're not talking about an array elsewhere.  Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: @J. B., seeing your example may I suggest improving the formulation of the question to "Is it possible to use array elements in a foreign key?"

Comment: I'll vote to close as unclear because it is not clear if you want a foreign key constraint or if you want help with writing the query (which is an independent question). Perhaps you can clarify that.

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis Your rephrasing is also unclear. A FK is a certain thing, and you aren't aren't talking about one. You aren't saying what you mean.

Comment: @philipxy , you are right. There is nothing in the body of the question that related to a foreign key (except the example). The author should clarify the question.

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis Yes the post is unclear. BUT: The example code doesn't have a FK either. It has a table that has some structured values that contain values that appear elsewhere once. That doesn't make the contained values FKs. It makes them values that appear elsewhere once. Know the definition of a term & use it when it applies & don't use it when it doesn't apply, use words that actually say what you mean. Certain values WOULD be FKs IF things were rearranged IN A CERTAIN WAY but things AREN'T that way so don't use the term WRONGLY.